# How does passport's authenticate function know which request to authenticate?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

The [passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/basic-digest/) use this to protect a route:

```
app.get('/api/me',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });
```

How does `authenticate()` know which request to authenticate? I don't pass the request to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `passport.authenticate` returns a function.

You can try this

```
console.log(passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }));
```

and it will print something like

```
function(req, res, next){ ... }
```

This means that the `app.get` will look something like this after your app starts

```
app.get('/api/me',
    function(req, res, next){
         // now passport has access to the "req" even though you didn't pass request to it
         // passport's authentication logic here
    },
    function(req, res) {
       res.json(req.user);
    });
```

Comment: Didn't realise it's a callback - I'm using TypeScript and the type declarations don't always make stuff like that clear. Thanks.